# pywinauto installation roadblock

Tags: python, sendkeys, pywinauto

I'm trying to install Pywinauto on my computer so that I can do some testing on it. But the problem is I keep getting the following error, everytime I try to install it.

```
C:\Users\Ganesha>python g:\pywinauto\pywinauto-0.4.0\pywinauto-0.4.0\setup.py install
  File "g:\pywinauto\pywinauto-0.4.0\pywinauto-0.4.0\setup.py", line 104
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought that there were dependencies, so thought I would install Ctypes and sendkey and then try.

firstly, am I proceeding in the right direction

so I installed Ctypes from : http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/ 
straight forwards, an msi file and installed.

But, sendkeys, I'm not able to browse/visit the page mentioned.

Is there a problem with the page??
if not what am I doing wrong?? 
where else can I get sendkeys from???

I'm using Python 3.2 on a Windows 7 machine.

Please help me and guide me. If this is a repeated question/query please point me to the previous thread/question and pardon my ignorance.

Regards,
Vinu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like pywinauto is for python <3 because the exception handling syntax is not applicable for Python 3 and thus the error you are seeing.

See PEP 3110:

```
PEP 3110: Catching exceptions. You must now use except SomeException as variable instead of except SomeException, variable. Moreover, the variable is explicitly deleted when the except block is left.
```

You should try using Python2.* instead.

Comment: I'm new to Python. Would you please elaborate a little more, as to how I can resolve this problem.

Regards,
Vinu

Comment: You should install Python version 2 to use the pywinauto. Python 2.72 is the latest version for Python2. http://python.org/getit/

Comment: Thank you, I shall try installing Python 2.72.

Answer (score 1):

http://sendkeys-ctypes.googlecode.com/files/SendKeys-ctypes-0.2.zip

And, probably, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6112025/1128985

Comment: Thanks for the location of the package, but the issue with the installation is still not fixed.