# How to emulate press and hold with pywin32

Tags: python, key, send, pywin32, win32com

I am trying to write a python script to send a press and hold key signal. Right now all I have managed to do is the following:

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("Wscript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("z")
```

However, this only sends an instantaneous key pressed event. What I would like to do is a key down and key up, something along the lines of:

```
shell.SendKeys("z{down}")
time.sleep(.25) 
shell.SendKeys("z{up}")
```

But I cannot find any documented way to achieve this.

EDIT: I also tried something along the lines of this:

```
import time
import win32com.client
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32con

time.sleep(2)
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("Wscript.Shell")
win32api.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_TOP, win32con.WM_CHAR, 90, 0) 
win32api.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, 90, 1) 
time.sleep(.25)
win32api.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_KEYUP, 90, 1)
```

The whole HWND thing is really a mystery to me - from the documentation I can't figure out how the hell to grab the correct window. Also, WM_CHAR seems to work, but WM_KEYDOWN/KEYUP hasn't really done anything.

Comment: I think this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2004267/673590) might be what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `win32api.PostMessage` to send `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages. See MSDN for documentation of the parameters. The constants are defined in `win32con` module.

Comment: Can you provide an example? The documentation is really difficult for me to sift through. See edit.