# 32 and 64 bit way of simulated key presses - Python

Tags: keyboard, key, sendkeys

Sorry for the vagueness but upon investigation I found the SendKeys module is the best way to be able to simulate keypresses in Python. But I found it is not compatible with 64 bit Windows or Python 2.7 (as far as I know).

Is there another way of reliably simulating, say pressing 3 keys all at once, and opening a notepad file inserting several characters on a 64 bit and 32 bit system?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2004267/63678) thread have some info. And you can try SendKeysCtypes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6112025/63678)