# How can I debug SendKeysCtypes on (win7 64bit, py2.7) further?

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, pywin32, sendkeys

Im trying to get SendKeysCtypes working on ***py2.7 and win7 64bit***.  [Here is src](https://bitbucket.org/markm/sendkeysctypes)

**Problem:**

Run [SendKeysCtypes.py](https://svn.openqa.org/svn/pywinauto/trunk/pywinauto/SendKeysCtypes.py) and nothing happens.  Tests should open notepad and write some text.

The problem code is this:

```
def GetInput(self):
    "Build the INPUT structure for the action"
    actions = 1
    # if both up and down
    if self.up and self.down:
        actions = 2

    inputs = (INPUT * actions)()

    vk, scan, flags = self._get_key_info()

    for inp in inputs:
        inp.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD

        inp._.ki.wVk = vk
        inp._.ki.wScan = scan
        inp._.ki.dwFlags |= flags

    # if we are releasing - then let it up
    if self.up:
        inputs[-1]._.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP

    return inputs

def Run(self):
    "Execute the action"
    inputs = self.GetInput()
    return SendInput(
        len(inputs),
        ctypes.byref(inputs),
        ctypes.sizeof(INPUT))
```

SendInput()  in above code does nothing.

**Other tests**

- I tried the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823762/sendkeys-for-python-3-1-on-windows/2004267#2004267) and it worked ok. But this code
  had some other issues.
- According to the author it [should work with py3.1](http://pywinauto.blogspot.se/2010/04/sendkeysctypes-release-for-some-value.html)
- [SendInput() returns '0'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , which means "blocked by another
  thread"
- A call to ctypes.GetLastError() gives us [error code 87](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which means "ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER"

And here we are stuck because my windows programming is very limited, can anyone shed some light on this?

**EDIT 1:**

- Following the "64bit is problem" trace, lead me to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833311/63678), will see if I can convert it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the `Structure` and `Union` classes you're using. I'll reproduce a snippet from [the code you linked to](https://bitbucket.org/markm/sendkeysctypes/src/68b60cd364e9d890c097a3927d2e2617e2784dda/SendKeysCtypes.py) with one of the classes as example here:

```py
class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    "A particular keyboard event"
    _pack_ = 2  # FIXME: don't do this
    _fields_ = [
        # C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~4/VC98/Include/winuser.h 4292
        ('wVk', WORD),
        ('wScan', WORD),
        ('dwFlags', DWORD),
        ('time', DWORD),
        ('dwExtraInfo', DWORD),  # FIXME: use correct data type
    ]
```

(The **FIXME**s were added by me to point out the problematic parts.)

The first is that you're using **`_pack_ = 2`**, which **is incorrect**. You should not use any `_pack_` alignment specifier at all. The defaults work fine both on 32-bit and on 64-bit Windows.

It's purely by chance that it worked with `_pack_ = 2` on 32-bit Windows: All 2-byte sized data types used in the code come in pairs and start on already aligned boundaries and therefore happen to produce the same structures as with 4-byte alignment.

However, under 64-bit Windows the fundamental alignment is 8 byte, so the structures would be misaligned and have wrong sizes if you used `_pack_ = 2` or `_pack_ = 4` there.

The second problem is that there's **no `ULONG_PTR` in `ctypes.wintypes`**, which would be the **correct data type for `dwExtraInfo`**. Under 32-bit Windows `ULONG_PTR` is an unsigned 32-bit integer whereas under 64-bit Windows it is an unsigned 64-bit integer.

The [MSDN article about Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) shows how it's defined:

```cpp
#if defined(_WIN64)
 typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR;
#else
 typedef unsigned long ULONG_PTR;
#endif
```

Using `DWORD` or `ULONG` for `dwExtraInfo` therefore only happens to work under 32-bit Windows and produces the wrong size otherwise.

While using some `POINTER` based data type instead would happen to produce a correctly aligned and sized structure, it would be wrong both in meaning as well as in usage, as `ULONG_PTR` is "an unsigned integer that can also store a (casted) pointer" rather than an actual pointer.

Looking through `wintypes`, you'll notice that `WPARAM` happens to be defined exactly like what `ULONG_PTR` is supposed to be. So a quick and dirty (but still reasonably robust) way to get `ULONG_PTR` would be:

```py
from ctypes.wintypes import WPARAM as ULONG_PTR
```

Alternatively, you could use a piece of code inspired by theirs and define it yourself:

```py
import ctypes

for ULONG_PTR in [ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_ulonglong]:
    if ctypes.sizeof(ULONG_PTR) == ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p):
        break
else:
    raise TypeError("cannot find a suitable type for ULONG_PTR")
```

Armed with those adaptions, you could define the structures like this:

```py
class MOUSEINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dw',          LONG),
        ('dy',          LONG),
        ('mouseData',   DWORD),
        ('dwFlags',     DWORD),
        ('time',        DWORD),
        ('dwExtraInfo', ULONG_PTR),
    ]


class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('wVk',         WORD),
        ('wScan',       WORD),
        ('dwFlags',     DWORD),
        ('time',        DWORD),
        ('dwExtraInfo', ULONG_PTR),
    ]


class HARDWAREINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('uMsg',    DWORD),
        ('wParamL', WORD),
        ('wParamH', WORD),
    ]


class _INPUT(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [
        ('mi', MOUSEINPUT),
        ('ki', KEYBDINPUT),
        ('hi', HARDWAREINPUT),
    ]


class INPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _anonymous_ = ['']
    _fields_ = [
        ('type', DWORD),
        ('', _INPUT),
    ]
```